# Idea for affich result in format json android

Tags: android, mysql, json

Good Morning
In my Android application, i have create a questionnaire.
 All result are registered in MySQL Database with the format Json. 
For the moment all question are in the same page and user will press validate after finishing all questions. But now i need to make every question in a separate page and user will press the button next to pass from one question (page) to another .
Please any one have an idea how could i do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragment for dispalying different questions , each question on one page inside an activity.